# is it possible to add classes into arrays in Java?

Tags: java, arrays

Is there any way to condense this code into an array? Each of the sprites corresponds with a separate class which has been declared previously. This is part of the game where it collects the x and y values of sprites from the different classes.

```
private void doDrawing(Graphics g) {
    Graphics2D g2d = (Graphics2D) g;

    g2d.drawImage(sprite.getImage(), sprite.getX(), 
        sprite.getY(), this);
    g2d.drawImage(sprite2.getImage(), sprite2.getX(), 
            sprite2.getY(), this);
    g2d.drawImage(sprite3.getImage(), sprite3.getX(), 
            sprite3.getY(), this);
    g2d.drawImage(sprite4.getImage(), sprite4.getX(), 
            sprite4.getY(), this);
    g2d.drawImage(sprite5.getImage(), sprite5.getX(), 
            sprite5.getY(), this);
    g2d.drawImage(sprite6.getImage(), sprite6.getX(), 
            sprite6.getY(), this);
    g2d.drawImage(sprite7.getImage(), sprite7.getX(), 
            sprite7.getY(), this);
    g2d.drawImage(sprite8.getImage(), sprite8.getX(), 
            sprite8.getY(), this);
    g2d.drawImage(sprite9.getImage(), sprite9.getX(), 
            sprite9.getY(), this);
    g2d.drawImage(sprite10.getImage(), sprite10.getX(), 
            sprite10.getY(), this);
    g2d.drawImage(sprite11.getImage(), sprite11.getX(), 
            sprite11.getY(), this);
    g2d.drawImage(sprite12.getImage(), sprite12.getX(), 
            sprite12.getY(), this);
    g2d.drawImage(sprite13.getImage(), sprite13.getX(), 
            sprite13.getY(), this);
    g2d.drawImage(sprite14.getImage(), sprite14.getX(), 
            sprite14.getY(), this);
    g2d.drawImage(sprite15.getImage(), sprite15.getX(), 
            sprite15.getY(), this);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You could have an array of sprites:

```
MySptrite[] sprites = ...;
for (MySprite sprite : sprites) {
    g2d.drawImage(sprite.getImage(), sprite.getX(), sprite.getY(), this);
}
```

Or, more conveniently, a `List`:

```
List<MySptrite> sprites = ...;
for (MySprite sprite : sprites) {
    g2d.drawImage(sprite.getImage(), sprite.getX(), sprite.getY(), this);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
public class Foo implements ImageObserver {

    private void doDrawing(Graphics g) {
        Sprite[] sprites = ...;
        Arrays.stream(sprites).forEach(sprite -> drawImage.accept((Graphics2D)g, sprite));
    }

    private final BiConsumer<Graphics2D, Sprite> drawImage = (g2d, sprite) -> g2d.drawImage(sprite.getImage(), sprite.getX(), sprite.getY(), this);
}
```

Comment: the thing is that each sprite is in its own separate class, would this still work?

Comment: @TalhaMajeed Give please example of these files!